# On Windows XP - how do I use PowerShell background jobs which require windows authentication

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to run some functions in the background of a PoSh script. The job never completes, but works fine when called normal. I've narrowed the problem down to the following line:

This line works fine:

```
$ws = New-WebServiceProxy  "http://host/Service?wsdl" -UseDefaultCredential
```

but this line blocks forever

```
start-job { New-WebServiceProxy "same url" -UseDefaultCredential } `
 | wait-job | Receive-Job
```

Some details: the service is local, and requires windows authentication. Client is XP & server 2003.

Why? How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ConvertFrom-SecureString and ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlets

Once run

```
$securestring = read-host -assecurestring
convertfrom-securestring $securestring | out-file c:\securestring
```

it will create a secured file on disk
after that you can use

```
$pass = Get-Content c:\securestring | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist “domain\administrator”,$pass
```

and

```
start-job { New-WebServiceProxy "same url" -Credential $cred } | wait-job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: That's helpfull, but only works as long as my password doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work. What OS are you running? XP or 2003 may be a problem.

```
start-job { 
        $zip = New-WebServiceProxy "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL"  -UseDefaultCredential 
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job

$zip | get-member -type method
```

Comment: The service requires windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any ASMX web services to test this against, but if you look at the help of Start-Job you'll see '-Authentication- and '-Credential'. The first specifies Default, Basic, Credssp, Digest, Kerberos, Negotiate, and NegotiateWithImplicitCredential. The second could be used to provide actual credentials to run the job.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get back Start-Job : The specified authentication mechanism "..." is not supported. Only "Default" is supported for this operation. And there doesn't seem to be any way to provide credential non-interactivly